# how to configure log4j.xml to get the debug info of "javax.net.debug"

Tags: java, debugging, log4j

I want to get the LDAP connect ssl handshake debug info ,so I set the system property "javax.net.debug" value "ssl,handshake" like this :

`System.property("javax.net.debug" , "ssl,handshake");`
but I didn't get the ssl debug info.In my project,using log4j.xml to control the debug info, so I want to know how to configure log4j.xml to get the debug info of "javax.net.debug"? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6):

Classes inside `javax.net` package would not write to `Log4J appenders` (infact they do not use Log4J library at all). Most probably they would output debug messages to `STDOUT` or `STDERR` streams of the running java process. Redirect these streams to file(s) on the disk and then you can get those messages logged in the file(s). If you are using some server (e.g. Tomcat or JBoss) then read the server's document on how to control I/O streams from these processes.

`Log4j.xml` has nothing to do here.

**EDIT:** If you are using Tomcat (or Jboss) then you may need to check the Log threshold for `ConsoleAppender` in `log4j.xml`. By default it is set as `INFO` and redirected to `console.log` file inside logs directory.

Answer (score 0):

SunJSSE has a built-in debug facility and is activated by the System property **javax.net.debug** (-Djavax.net.debug=all). The debug messages printed to STDOUT.

I extended java.io.PrintStream class and by forwarding all System.out.print methods calls to print to the logger, I get the JSSE debug messages in my application file log configured by log4j.

I activate the redirection only then application's logger is in debug level:

```
if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
    StdOutLogger.enable();
```

Deactivate the redirection by calling:

```
StdOutLogger.disable();
```

Please review StdOutLogger class:

```
package com.mydomain.util.log4j;

import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class StdOutLogger extends PrintStream
{   
    private static Logger logger = 
    LoggerFactory.getLogger(StdOutLogger.class);

    private static volatile StdOutLogger systemOutLogger;
    private static PrintStream originalStream = System.out;
    private static boolean isEnabled = false;

    private StringBuilder builder;     
    private String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");    

private StdOutLogger(PrintStream original) 
{
    super(original);
    builder = new StringBuilder();
    logger.debug("Reassign standard output stream to log" + lineSeparator);
}

public static StdOutLogger getInstance()
{ 
    if(systemOutLogger == null)
    { 
        synchronized(StdOutLogger.class)
        { 
            if(systemOutLogger == null) 
                systemOutLogger = new StdOutLogger(originalStream);
        } 
    } 
    return systemOutLogger; 
}

/**
 * Enable forwarding System.out.println calls to the logger
 */
public static void enable() 
{
    if (isEnabled)
        return;

    systemOutLogger = StdOutLogger.getInstance();
    try 
    {
        System.setOut(systemOutLogger);
        isEnabled = true;
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        logger.error("Failed to reassign the standard output stream to log: " + e.getMessage());
    }   
}
/**
 * Disable forwarding to the logger resetting the standard output to the console
 */
public static void disable() 
{
    if (!isEnabled)
        return;
    try 
    {
        System.setOut(originalStream);      
        isEnabled = false;
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        logger.error("Failed to reassign the standard output stream: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    systemOutLogger = null;
}

@Override
public void println() 
{
    originalStream.println();
    printToLogger(lineSeparator, false);
}

@Override
public void print(final String s) 
{
    originalStream.print(s);
    printToLogger(s, false);                
}

@Override
public void print(final int i) 
{
    originalStream.print(i);
    printToLogger(String.valueOf(i), false);
}

@Override
public void print(final long l) 
{
    originalStream.print(l);
    printToLogger(String.valueOf(l), false);
}

@Override
public void print(final float f) 
{
    originalStream.print(f);
    printToLogger(String.valueOf(f), false);
}

@Override
public void print(final double d) 
{
    originalStream.print(d);
    printToLogger(String.valueOf(d), false);
}

@Override
public void print(final Object obj) 
{
    originalStream.print(obj);
    printToLogger(String.valueOf(obj), false);
}

@Override
public void print(char c) 
{
    originalStream.print(c);
    printToLogger(String.valueOf(c), false);
}

@Override
public void print(boolean b) 
{
    originalStream.print(b);
    printToLogger(String.valueOf(b), false);
}

@Override
public void println(final String s) 
{
    originalStream.println(s);
    printToLogger(s, true);
}

@Override
public void println(final int i) 
{
    originalStream.println(i);
    printToLogger(String.valueOf(i), true);
}

@Override
public void println(final long l) 
{
    originalStream.println(l);
    printToLogger(String.valueOf(l), true);
}

@Override
public void println(final float f) 
{
    originalStream.println(f);
    printToLogger(String.valueOf(f), true);
}

@Override
public void println(final double d) 
{
    originalStream.println(d);
    printToLogger(String.valueOf(d), true);
}

@Override
public void println(final Object obj) {
    originalStream.println(obj);
    printToLogger(String.valueOf(obj), true);
}

@Override
public void println(char c) {
    originalStream.println(c);
    printToLogger(String.valueOf(c), true);
}

@Override
public void println(boolean b) {
    originalStream.println(b);
    printToLogger(String.valueOf(b), true);
}

@Override
public PrintStream append(CharSequence csq, int start, int end) 
{
    CharSequence cs = (csq == null ? "null" : csq);
    printToLogger(cs.subSequence(start, end).toString(), false);
    return this;
}

@Override
public void write(int b) 
{
    originalStream.write(b);
    printToLogger(String.valueOf((char)b), false);                  
}

@Override
public void write(byte buf[], int off, int len) 
{
    originalStream.write(buf, off, len);
    if (buf == null) 
    {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    } 
    else if ((off < 0) || (off > buf.length) || (len < 0) ||
               ((off + len) > buf.length) || ((off + len) < 0)) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    } 
    else if (len == 0) {
        return;
    }
    byte[] pb = new byte[len];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++) {
        pb[i] = (buf[off + i]);
    }
    String str = new String(pb);
    printToLogger(str, false);              
}

@Override
public PrintStream printf(String format, Object ... args)
{
    return format(format, args); 
}

@Override          
public PrintStream format(String format, Object ... args) 
{
    originalStream.format(format, args);
    printToLogger(String.format(format, args), false);
    return this;
}

@Override
public PrintStream format(Locale l, String format, Object ... args)
{
    originalStream.format(l, format, args);
    printToLogger(String.format(format, args), false);
    return this;
}          

@Override
public void flush() 
{
    originalStream.flush();
    if (builder.length() > 0)
    {
        logger.debug(builder.toString());
        builder = new StringBuilder();
    }
    //builder.append(lineSeparator);
}

private void printToLogger(String str, boolean isNewLine) 
{       
    if (str.endsWith(lineSeparator))
    {
        int endIndex = str.lastIndexOf(lineSeparator);
        str = str.substring(0, endIndex);
        isNewLine = true;
    }
    builder.append(str);
    if (isNewLine)
    {
        logger.debug(builder.toString());
        builder = new StringBuilder(); 
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JBoss you can configure jboss-log4j.xml to print all STDOUT messages to stdout.log.

Excerpt of solution from : https://access.redhat.com/solutions/68949

> Add the following to $JBOSS_HOME/server/$PROFILE/conf/jboss-log4j.xml

```
<appender name="STDOUTLOG" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
    <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/stdout.log"/>
    <param name="Append" value="false"/>
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] (Thread) Message\n -->
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] (%t) %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="STDERRLOG" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
    <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/stderr.log"/>
    <param name="Append" value="false"/>
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] (Thread) Message\n -->
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] (%t) %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

...(snip)...

<category name="STDOUT" additivity="false">
    <priority value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUTLOG"/>
</category>

<category name="STDERR" additivity="false">
    <priority value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDERRLOG"/>
</category>
```

P.S: Don't include the separator text **...(snip)...** in the above code snippet. It is only present to tell you to insert the config in the correct section of the config file.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have configured the logger? (in addition to your System.property)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//LOGGER" "http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/doc-files/log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p %c.%M:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="/var/opt/log/mylogs.log" />
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="5" />
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="5MB" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %C{2}.%M - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="javax.net.debug">
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="file" />
    </logger>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: `javax.net` classes don't use `Log4j` logger API. You can't control its log behavior like this.